# Struggles with installing curl on windows 7

Tags: php, curl

I've been trying to install curl on my work computer for awhile and I keep getting into problems. I have un-commented the extension php_curl.dll in the php.ini. But every time I try to run a program with curl in it, I get an error saying that the curl function is not defined.  I've done phpinfo to make sure it is in the right path and it is. I am not using Xammp, or Wammp.

Comment: `I am not using Xammp, or Wammp` so what are you using? have you checked the .dll exists in the `php/ext` folder?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone: Probably he used the php binaries for windows or he compiled php manually from sources.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to respond, I switched to xammp and it worked out. I was trying to install apache, mysql, and php individually and I kept running into problems. I got my admin to allow me to install xammp and it's been fine.